# Scala equivalent for ActiveSupport's Object.try in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scala, apache-spark, chaining

The [`try` method](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) is a common extension to core Ruby. For example, it's available by default in Rails. `try` executes a method or a block of code on an object only if it is not `nil` (Ruby's `null`). It's usage comes in three flavors:

1. Calling a method on a non-`nil` object and returning the result:
   `customer_or_nil.try(:save)`.
2. Chaining an arbitrary block of code in an expression if the result so far is not `nil`:
   `obj.try { |non_nil_obj| do_something(non_nil_obj) }`.
3. An extension of (2) used not for optional processing but as a way to continue a chained expression where the method in step n+1 requires an argument that must be calculated based on the result of step n:
   `data.analyze.try { |result| result.compress(optimal_settings(result)) }.save`

I am specifically interested in the Scala equivalent of (3) or an alternative Scala idiom that would allow, for example, this code related to Apache Spark's [`DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame):

```scala
val df = ctx.sql("select * from my_table")
df.
  repartition(max(1, df.rdd.partitions.size / 4)).
  saveAsTable("repartitioned_table")
```

to be refactored into something like the following (using Ruby syntax)

```rb
ctx.
  sql("select * from my_table").
  try { |df| df.repartition(max(1, df.rdd.partitions.size / 4)) }.
  saveAsTable("repartitioned_table")
```

The goal of the refactoring is to improve readability by maintaining a single method chain and reduce scope pollution by keeping `df` tightly scoped to the step in the chain where it is absolutely needed.

**Note:** I am specifically not interested in discussions of the pros and cons of using `Option` for optional processing as this is not the main use case of `try` this question is concerned with.

Comment: A for-comprehension should do the job. `Try` in Scala is a monad, meaning that `flatmap()` is defined on it. The way `flatmap()` works on a `Try` is to apply its argument to the successful path. `for{ df <- ctx.sql(...); rep <- repartiion( ... ); sat <- saveAsTable(...); }`

Comment: @BobDalgleish you missed the purpose of the question: I was looking for an answer that supported method chaining. Take a look at Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the standard library, but an equivalent to 3 is easy to write (`try` is a keyword, so renamed to `ap` (short for `apply`)):

```
implicit class TryOp[A](x: A) {
  def ap[B](f: A => B): B = f(x)
}

ctx.
  sql("select * from my_table").
  ap { df => df.repartition(max(1, df.rdd.partitions.size / 4)) }.
  saveAsTable("repartitioned_table")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `null.ap(identity _) //
<console>:12: error: value ap is not a member of Null`

Comment: @JörgWMittag I can reproduce your error above but, when I use `ap` with what should be `null` values coming from Spark SQL (using an `Any`-valued variable) I get no error.

Comment: Alexey, any way to address the problem @JörgWMittag identified?

Comment: If you give a type to `null`, e.g. `(null: String).ap ...` or `val x: String = null; x.ap ...`, it'll work. But `null` by itself has a special type `Null`, and it seems you can't have any implicit conversions on it. This looks like a compiler bug to me, I've asked about it at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/jpVi3_AlF4E